# Developing a simple windowed app for Linux

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, window-managers

Okay, I'd like to write a simple C app for Linux (say Ubuntu with Gnome) that would do the following:

1. Open a Window
2. Draw something in that window using a main loop, e.g. the current loop number. I don't want to use controls, but to draw directly on the window surface
3. Close the window & the app

I can do that in Windows, but I've no idea how I could do that in Linux.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various "Hello World" examples for X11 programming.

Using GTK+:
http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk-tutorial/2.13/c39.html

Using Qt:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/tutorials-widgets-toplevel.html

Using wxWidgets:
http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/hello.htm

There are a lot more toolkits: Fox, FLTK, Tk, EFL ...

So far these have all been cross-platform, so let's have a look at X11-specific exampls:

This is using Xlib:
[http://en.literateprograms.org/Special:Downloadcode/Hello_World_(C,_Xlib)](http://en.literateprograms.org/Special%3aDownloadcode/Hello_World_%28C,_Xlib%29)

And this is using Xcb:
http://xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial/basicwindowsanddrawing/

Comment: Thanks a lot @datenwolf! The simple Hello_world X_lib tutorial seems perfect for my case!

Answer (score 4):

Unless you want a full-blown GUI (in which case I'd recommend [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) or [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/)), then [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) is a very popular and extremely simple free cross-platform library that gives you a drawing surface and some simple IO facilities. It's natively C, but has bindings to a large number of other languages.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to draw something, why not just use OpenGL and GLUT. The latter provides simple methods to create a window with an OpenGL context.

Setting up a GLUT application is very straighforward and there are lots of tutorials out there , e.g. [Lighthouse3d.com](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/glut/). This tutorial works with visual studio, but it's not hard to translate this to compiling an application on Linux.

Alternatively, you could also work with [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products), which is a more advanced and easy to use GUI toolkit, and which would not necessarily require you to write OpenGL code.

Comment: OpenGL requires GLX being available to be reasonably performant. Not always the case.

Comment: Thanks! Honestly, I was trying to do the same thing using EGL :-D

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned C, there is [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) if you want to make use of GTK+ for a nice little editor that allows you to draw controls onto a window.

Alternatively if you have access to a C++ compiler you can have a look at [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) which provides similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're familiar with making gui apps in windows I'm going to take a guess that you've done it with .net or something similar. An easy transition would be to use mono. A cross platform .NET development platform - http://mono-project.com/Main_Page

There's also has a variety gui toolkits to use: http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits

Comment: Not that the link you posted wouldn't be useful in a more general sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw directly onto the window, have you considered X11?
It's not going to be as nice as working with a toolkit like GTK or Qt, but it's about as low level as you can get in the windowing system.

I don't have any experience with programming straight X11, so I can't recommend any starting material.

Comment: Well, yes. I was thinking of that, too but I am not competent with X11 either :-|